# Print do Dicionário saindo vazio - Webscrapping/python/xpath

Tags: python, web-scraping

Galera, nao consigo entender por que o resultado dessa scrapp sai um dicionário vazio.
Poderiam me ajudar a entender qual meu erro?

```
import requests 
from lxml import html

quimicos = []

resp = requests.get(url="https://www.chemicalbook.com/ProductCASList_12_0_EN.htm", headers ={ 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.87 Safari/537.36' })

tree = html.fromstring(html=resp.content)

Linhas = tree.xpath("//table[@id='ContentPlaceHolder1_ProductClassDetail']/tbody/tr") 


for linha in Linhas:
    l = { 
    'Agente' : linha.xpath(".//td[2]/a/text()"), 
    'CAS' : linha.xpath(".//td[3]/a/text()") 
    }
    quimicos.append(l)

print(len(quimicos))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dê uma olhada nesse código...
Veja se entende.. Qualquer dúvida pergunte..

```
import requests 
from lxml import html


def get_data(url_total):
    resp = requests.get(url=url_total, headers ={ 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.87 Safari/537.36' })
    tree = html.fromstring(html=resp.content)
    tr_elements = tree.xpath('//tr')
    total = 0
    col=[]
    for t in tr_elements:
        total+=1
        name=t.text_content().strip()
        print ('%d:"%s"'%(total,name))
        col.append((name,[]))


def main():
    url="https://www.chemicalbook.com" 
    resto_url = "/ProductCASList_12_0_EN.htm"
    resp = requests.get(url=url+resto_url, headers ={ 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.87 Safari/537.36' })
    tree = html.fromstring(html=resp.content)
    proximos = tree.xpath('//*[@id="form1"]/div[2]/div[9]//a/@href')
    get_data(url+resto_url)
    for p in proximos:
        url_total = url+p
        #print(url_total)
        get_data(url_total)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Utilizando a biblioteca BeautifulSoup:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests 
import json


def get_data(cell, contador, resposta_parcial):
    if contador == 0:
        pass
    elif contador == 1:
        resposta_parcial.append(json.dumps("Chemical Name:"+cell.text.strip()))
        print("Chemical Name", str(cell.text))
    elif contador == 2:
        resposta_parcial.append(json.dumps("CAS:"+cell.text.strip()))
        print("CAS", str(cell.text))
    elif contador == 3:
        resposta_parcial.append(json.dumps("MF:"+cell.text.strip()))
        print("MF", str(cell.text))


def main():
    resposta_total = []
    resposta_parcial = []
    page_url = 'https://www.chemicalbook.com/ProductCASList_12_0_EN.htm'
    req = requests.get(page_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')

    tables = soup.find_all('table')

    for t in tables:
        rows = t.find_all('tr', recursive=False)
        for row in rows:
            cells = row.find_all(['td'], recursive=False)
            contador = 0
            resposta_parcial = []
            for cell in cells:
                get_data(cell, contador, resposta_parcial)
                contador+=1
                if contador == 4:
                    contador = 0
            resposta_total.append(resposta_parcial)

    for r in resposta_total:
        print(r)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Bom dia, Vinicius. Muito obrigado pela atenção. O Código que voce refez parece mais lógico e estruturado, achei mto bom! Mas ao executar tive alguns erros e tentei compartilhar aqui mas excede o limite de caracteres: Traceback (most recent call last): (linhas 33, 29, 15 e 19) - coloquei assim pra caber na resposta*
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x8c' in position 16: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: Qual versão do python voce está usando?
Provavelmente esse erro é sobre caracteres especiais..

Comment: To usando a 3.7.4

Comment: Eu to usando o 3.6... Acredito que não seja isso entao..
Eu testei esse código em um Linux.. Esse erro pode ser por alguma coisa do Windows tambem.. Não consegui replicar o erro na minha máquina..
Se eu descobrir algo te aviso..
Dê uma olhada nessa resposta tambem:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27092833/unicodeencodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-encode-characters

Comment: Vou olhar. Obrigado pela atenção, Vinicius!

Comment: Coloque esse código e veja qual encode que seu request esta utilizando:
print("Encoding: " + str(resp.encoding)).
O resultado deve ser 'utf-8'.

Veja:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44203397/python-requests-get-returns-improperly-decoded-text-instead-of-utf-8

Comment: Executei e saiu isso mesmo Encoding: utf-8

Comment: Achei o erro! Era apenas nessa parte: Estava assim ('//*[@id='form1']/div[2]/div[9]//a/@href') e eu mudei pra ficar assim ("//*[@id='form1']/div[2]/div[9]//a/@href") Depois que mudei deu certo!!! caraaaaaio que felicidade hahahahahaha :DDDDD Agora to tentando salvar o arquivo em formato json

Comment: As aspas simples de fora estava conflitando com as de dentro.. Voce pode utilizar destas duas formas:
('//*[@id="form1"]/div[2]/div[9]//a/@href')
ou
 ("//*[@id='form1']/div[2]/div[9]//a/@href")

Comment: Entendi!! :D obrigado demais mesmo, Vinicius!! Eu mesclei o meu antigo código com este novo para tentar gerar o arquivo json, mas não estou conseguindo. Vou postar mais se eu conseguir

Comment: Por gentileza, Vinicius, poderia me ajudar a gerar o arquivo em Json ou CSV tal como é mostrado no site? Pretendo fazer um tratamento de dados desses arquivos em powerBi

Comment: Atualizei a resposta Marcelo. Depois de uma olhada na versão com a biblioteca BeautifulSoup

Comment: Toppppper demais!!! Vou dar uma olhada sim!! muito obrigado!!!